# momentjs does not change the date / time in accordance with the specified timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am using moment and moment-timezone to output the presence date (for any timezone). For my timezone (Asia/Jakarta), Today at 2020-04-22 17:30:00 is correct. However, it always outputs 2020-04-22 17:30:00 for any timezone, which is incorrect.In the example below, it should display 2020-04-22 15:30:00

````
const presence_end = "2020-04-22T17:30:00+07:00";
const end = Moment(presence_end).tz('Asia/Jayapura').format();
console.log(end) //the output is 2020-04-22 17:30:00```
````

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite replicate your results, however I hope this is helpful.

From the code below, the time seems to be changing correctly, from Asia/Jakarta time (+07:00) to Asia/Jayapura time (+9:00).

If it is 17:30 hours in Jakarta, it should be 19:30 hours in Jayapura.

```js
const presence_end = "2020-04-22T17:30:00+07:00";
const endJakarta = moment(presence_end).tz('Asia/Jakarta').format();
console.log("Presence_end (Asia/Jakarta):", endJakarta )
console.log("Presence_end (UTC):", moment(presence_end).toISOString());
const endJayapura = moment(presence_end).tz('Asia/Jayapura').format();
console.log("Presence_end (Asia/Jayapura):", endJayapura);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```